# I get push notification from AWS sns into my emulator build in Android but the same doesnt work in a physical device

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

The facts as below,

1) Entire configuration part is complete, hence I am able to successfully receive the push notification from AWS SNS, but the same is not being received in my physical device, when the push notification is triggered.

2) I have overridden the `onMessageReceived` method with my own implementation and the push notification is rendered perfectly in emulator, also added logs to check if this function is called, the logs are captured in emulator but not in real device, based on which I came to the conclusion that the method is not called.

3) I tried the scenario both in foreground and background and neither of those work.

4) I have logged from the SNS and from the cloud watch logs, I can see the messageid, which shows the notification delivery was successful.

5) Using the versions, 
`implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2"`

also tried updating but no luck, `implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0"`

6) Also , basic implementations like device registration using token, adding the firebasemessageservice in manifest, are all done as a result of which the emulator is working fine.

7) This seems to be not specific to Android OS versions since i tried using google pixel 3 running android 10 and used the emulator Pixel 2 using same android 10 and the above issue remains.

8) Also , I am using `String default = remoteMessage.getData().get("default");` to get the notification content but this info is secondary since this is in `onMessageReceived` method.